# Changing Colour of Leaflet Layer Control Box

Tags: leaflet, web-mapping

Is it possible to reference the box in the CSS to change the colour of the layer selection box? Would be great to change it away from the standard white.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.leaflet-control-layers-expanded { background: #ff0000; }
```

make sure you add this after leaflet css is loaded so that it overrides the default style

in your  for example:

```
<style>.leaflet-control-layers-expanded { background: #ff0000; }</style>
```

or else edit `leaflet.css` directly (line 302 in [this example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html))

Comment: Ah thank you very much! I should have thought to look in the leaflet css.. Have a great day :)